# When exactly is copy constructor called?

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-constructor

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
private:
    int x;
public:
    A(){x=10;}
    
    A(int m){x=m; cout << "int m constructor" << m << endl;}
    A(A& a){cout << "copy constructor:"<<a.x<<"\n"; x=a.x;}
    A(A&& a){cout <<"move constructor:"<<a.x<<"\n"; x=a.x;}

};

int main(){
    A a(100);
    A b = a;

    A d = A(30);
    
}
```

which outputs the following:

```
int m constructor100
copy constructor:100
int m constructor30
```

I was expecting it to output

```
int m constructor100
copy constructor:100
copy constructor:30
```

because the constructor function (`A(30)`) is called.
But somehow the compiler optimises it?
Also `A d = A(A(30))` also prints `int m constructor30`.
Is there some compiler optimization happening here?

Comment: Your last line (`A d = A(30)`) is actually a direct initialization of `d` (no need to create a temporary and then copy construct/assign).

Comment: *When exactly is copy constructor called?* -- Whenever the compiler makes a copy.  There is no *exact* answer as to the number of times, and that is especially the case if you compile your program using different options.  That's why when writing user-defined copy constructors, it should be coded to have no side-effects, no complex "business logic", etc. because you won't reliably predict exactly when it will be called.

Comment: `A d = A(30)` is evaluated as if it were `A d(30)`, because C++ presumes that there is no benefit in default-constructing an object only to immediately assign something else to it.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision ; but also you should implement assignment ops, to see the whole picture in different scenarios.

Comment: Side-effects in constructors are not guaranteed to be executed, because constructors *can be* (and as of C++17 and later, *must be*) elided where they are redundant.  It's not a "compiler optimization" inasmuch as it is a requirement by the language.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line `A d = A(30)` and `A d = A(A(30))` is the [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).